# Why does the INSERT not seem to work in Python SQLite3 here?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

So my problem is as follows: I can't seem to insert a value into a row that was `None` before. Suppose there's 5 columns: a, b, c, d, e. e is the primary key (set to `autoincrement`). First, I insert values for 3 columns (a, b, c) into the row. The `autoincrement` is computed during the insertion so the value for e is automatically inserted. At this point, the value for d is `None`. Then I use a string concantenated with the computed primary key to insert into my previously uninserted column of the row: d. However, this final insert does not seem to work.

After the first insert, the value for column d shows up as `None` in that row (as it should). But the `None` remains even after the second insert.

Here's a snippet:

```
c.execute(f'''INSERT INTO table(a, b, c) VALUES(?,?,?)''', (val_a, val_b, val_c))
c.execute(f'''SELECT * FROM table WHERE b = ('{val_b}')''')
val_d = 'string' + str(primary_key_of_previously_inserted_row)  //accessed via c.fetchall()
c.execute(f'''INSERT INTO table(d) VALUES('{val_d}')''')
conn.commit()
c.execute(f'''SELECT * FROM table WHERE b = ('{val_b}')''')
print(c.fetchall())  // this is where it prints the None which still persists after the second insert
conn.commit()
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: `INSERT` always adds rows to your table. You probably meant to use `UPDATE`?

Comment: Yes! That fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to Select
 c.execute(f'''SELECT * FROM table WHERE e = ('{primary_key_of_previously_inserted_row}')''')

since e is your primary field and will be unique. You might have a record where val_b is not unique in your table.
In which case maybe it is writing to the first instance found?

Comment: That does not seem to have an effect on the second insert. It's actually just one row that I want to change.